# "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character" Error when passing multiple variables from AJAX to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, variables

I am using AJAX to pass variables from a form to a PHP page to process data at a database.

Once the user clicks a button it fires a the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {

        /* validate the fields */
        var firstDate= "11/10/2014"
        var secondDate = "10/10/2014"
        var myString = "some Text";
        var myArray = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "123-123-33gf"];

        processIT(firstDate, secondDate, muString, myArray);

    });/* end of submit */

});

function processIT(firstDate, secondDate, muString, myArray) {
    var response = ""; 
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api.php',           // the script to call to get data
            type: "POST", 
            data: {
                firstDate: firstDate, 
                secondDate : secondDate , 
                myString : myString , 
                myArray : myArray , 
            },                 // you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
            dataType: 'json',         // return data format
            success: function(data) { //
                alert(data);
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
             },
        });
    });
    return response;
}
```

The api.php page has the following

```
<?php 


    if ( isset($_POST["firstDate"]) && !empty($_POST["firstDate"])){
        $response .= "<p>firstDate= " . $_POST["firstDate"] . "</p>"; 
    }
    else $response .= " 1 ";
    if ( isset($_POST["secondDate"]) && !empty($_POST["secondDate"])){
        $response .= "<p>secondDate = " . $_POST["secondDate"] . "</p>";
    }
    else $response .= " 2 ";
    if ( isset($_POST["myString"]) && !empty($_POST["myString"])){
        $response .= "<p>myString = " . $_POST["myString"] . "</p>";
    }
    else $response .= " 3 ";
    if ( isset($_POST["myArray"]) && !empty($_POST["myArray"])){
        $response .= "<p>myArray = " . $_POST["myArray"] . "</p>";
    }
    else $response .= " 4 ";

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

But when I click the button I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

But if I change the POST to GET, I can see the passed variables, but still get the same error.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse` means that the JSON returned from the server is invalid.

Comment: so i am passing invalid data that in return is returned invalid?

Comment: P.S. `$_POST["myArray"]` is an array, so concatenating it to a string isn't going to be very helpful.  In fact, that may be printing a warning!  And that could be in the response which would make it invalid JSON.

Comment: ALSO... why do you have `console.log` in your PHP?!  That's most definitely going to throw an error.

Comment: Just look at what the actual response to the request is in the network panel of your browser’s development tools – most likely that will tell you already where you messed it up.

Comment: $response contains an string json_encode cannot change this to an json in a nice way. Also there is no header indicating that you are returning json. Also checkout the manual for a nice code example:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
`code`
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>`code`

Comment: @MartinDiphoorn: `json_encode` can work on strings, and the header isn't needed (`dataType: 'json'` will figure it out).  From the docs: `json_encode()` will generate JSON that is a simple value (that is, neither an object nor an array) if given a string, integer, float or boolean as an input value.

Comment: Also also, you have `$_POST["myString "]`.  Why is there a space there?  Your key is `"myString"`, not `"myString "`.

Comment: I was typing too fast. I realized only afterwards that the console.log was not supposed to be there. I removed it. I tried the stringify but it did not work. The space by the variable was also a typo, my code did not have it. I do not get the json encode error, but I am not able to get the posted data. I only get 1 2 3 4, and that tells me that the posted variables are eitehr empty or not psoted? Any idea?

Comment: Just a note, you can't do `return response;` in your `processIT` function.  AJAX is *asynchronous*, which means it runs in the background and calls its callback whenever it's ready.  You can't *return* from an AJAX call.  Also, why do you have `$(function () {` inside `processIT`?

Comment: What do you see if you just did `echo json_encode($_POST); die();`?

Comment: Voting to close as “too broad” – simply because the amount of stuff you are doing wrong here in one go is just too much, and therefor the basics we would have to teach you are too many as well. You need to go do your homework on some basics of PHP _and_ JavaScript first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PHP file is not outputting a valid JSON response, that's why `JSON.parse` is throwing an error.  There are a number of errors in your PHP code, and those errors are being included in the output, thus making an invalid JSON response.

```
console.log("firstDate" + $_POST["firstDate"]);
```

This is not valid PHP code.  PHP doesn't have `console.log()`.  It has `echo`.  P.S. You use `.` to concatenate strings in PHP, not `+.`

```
$_POST["secondDate "]
$_POST["myString "]
$_POST["myArray "]
```

These keys.  There is no space at the end.  They should be:

```
$_POST["secondDate"]
$_POST["myString"]
$_POST["myArray"]
```

Finally, `$_POST["myArray"]` is an *array*.  You can't concatenate it to a string.  Try this:

```
$response .= "<p>myArray = ".implode(', ', $_POST["myArray"])."</p>";
```

Comment: I fixed those issues. Now I do not get the json error anymore. But I am also not getting the variables passed. I do see them being passed in the fierbug console, but the return tells me that the values are either empty or not submitted.

Comment: If you just do `echo json_encode($_POST); die();`, what do you see?

Comment: ...and you see them being passed in Firebug's request tab?

Comment: I removed the stringify and now i see the variables i am passing.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` was incorrect, you shouldn't have added that.  So, if you're seeing the variables now, that means it should be working.  Remove the `echo json_encode($_POST);`, and see if your code works.

Comment: Buttom line, I had to change the type:json to html and that worked. I was able to echo out the variables, but json was complaining about returning the html formated string.

Comment: JSON is "normally" used to encode objects/arrays (that can contain strings, numbers, objects, or arrays).  You *can* `json_encode` a string, but sometimes it doesn't decode.  If it works as you want, then it's fine :-)